# Define generic method can open all activities

Tags: java, android

Can i define an activity in parent class of all activities that that can open new activity like this method that working:

```
public class ActivityBase extends Activity{
    public <T extends Activity,U  extends Activity> void openActivity()
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(T.this, U.class);
        T.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}

public class ActivityChield extends ActivityBase{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_warning_unregistered_shipping);

        // Set widgets reference
        btnOpenActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_wus_select_violation);

        // Set widgets event listener
        setListeners();
    }

    private void setListeners()
    {
        btnOpenActivity.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                openActivity<ActivityChield , OtherActivity>();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code is not working . Please help me how can i define a method that can open all activities with one method.

Comment: Have you considered making an interface with the openActivity method and make Activities implement it?

Comment: No, you cannot, because of type erasure. At runtime, the type `T` and `U` are unknown, so you cannot use them as types (as in `U.class` for instance).

Comment: Also I don't understand what exactly are you trying to achieve here… what's the purpose of this pseudo-factory?

Comment: But if the all T's and U's are Activities in any case, it seems to me that the behaviour could be implemented in a contract interface. Not sure if i understand the intent though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I don't think this way is a perfect solution. Better is to write the calling code when you need.*

By the way here is a solution for your question

```
public void openActivity(Class<?> calledActivity) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, calledActivity);
    this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

And you can call it as

```
openActivity(OtherActivity.class);
```

Comment: Just did something similar myself, however for some type safety I preferred the method declared something like `public <T extends Activity> void openActivity(Class<T> calledActivity) { ... }`